# How do I get involved with the Ubuntu kernel?

Tags: kernel

How do I get involved with the Ubuntu kernel?

Answer (score 5):

The kernel team is always interested in getting community help on the kernel. We need help triaging incoming bugs, reviewing patches proposed for the kernel, testing kernel images as well as helping to fix launchpad bugs. For more details see "[Getting Involved](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/GettingInvolved)".

You may also want to check out the [Kernel Team's FAQ](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/FAQ) and the [Kernel Team's wiki documentation](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel).

Comment: I love your answer! I am trying to mark it right but the check button is not there